# Lodash return array of values if the path is valid

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have the following object and lodash "queries" in Node.js (I'm simply running `node` in the terminal):

```
var obj = {
  a: [{
    b: [{
      c: "apple"
    },
    {
      d: "not apple"
    },
    {
      c: "pineapple"
    }]
  }]
};

> _.get(obj, "a[0].b[0].c")
'apple'

> _.get(obj, "a[0].b[1].c")
undefined

> _.get(obj, "a[0].b[2].c")
'pineapple'
```

My question is: is there a way to return an array of values where the path was found to be valid?

Example:

```
> _.get(obj, "a[].b[].c")
['apple', 'pineapple']
```

Comment: Do you want to get result array for the specific path, something `a[0].b`? Or any path, as you provided in the question?

Comment: Look at jsonpath. https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath

Comment: Thanks to @Tomalak's advice. This task would be pretty easy using jsonpath: `jsonpath.query(obj, '$.a[*].b[*].c');`

Comment: Thanks to @Tomalak and shaochuancs I've got what I wanted. I would appreciate it if one of you would submit it as the answer.

Comment: Write the answer yourself - you already have working code so all you need to do is copy it, write a short paragraph about it and you're done. I'll upvote, everybody wins. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Tomalak has suggested in a comment, the solution was to use JSONPath instead of Lodash.

Their github page: https://github.com/dchester/jsonpath

Example:

```
> var jp = require("jsonpath")
> var obj = {
   a: [{
     b: [{
       c: "apple"
     },
     {
       d: "not apple"
     },
     {
       c: "pineapple"
     }]
   }]
 };

> jp.query(obj, "$.a[*].b[*].c")
[ 'apple', 'pineapple' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this will be the most efficient or what you need but
can you use _.each or _.map to create an array if some conditions are valid? 
maybe something like

```
let first = _.map(object, (item) => {
  //change logic for maybe 
  if(item.b.c) {
    return item.b.c
  }
})
//filter out nulls
let second = _.without(first, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following function may help without using any additional libraries.

```
function getall(input, path = "", accumulator = []) {
  path = path.split(".");
  const head = path.shift();
  if (input && input[head] !== undefined) {
    if (!path.length) {
        accumulator.push(input[head]);
    } else if (Array.isArray(input[head])) {
            input[head].forEach(el => {
                getall(el, path.join('.'), accumulator);
            });
    } else {
        getall(input[head], path.join('.'), accumulator);
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
}
```

Samples

```
> getall(obj, 'a.b')
[ [ { c: 'apple' }, { d: 'not apple' }, { c: 'pineapple' } ] ]
> getall(obj, 'a.b.c')
[ 'apple', 'pineapple' ]
> getall(obj, 'a.b.d')
[ 'not apple' ]
> getall(obj, 'a.b.e')
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using flatMap and map

> _(obj.a).flatMap('b').map('c').compact();